# Beginner: Quick Constructor Q

Tags: c++

I began C++ just a week or so ago and recently covered constructors in class. Using Code::Blocks, I've come up with a basic class. My question is: why can't I simply have {m_f = f;} as compared to {float m_f = f;}? My compiler didn't like when I tried it without the float in front.

```
class classyClass
{
    public:
       classyClass(int x=0, int y=0) {m_x = x; m_y = y;}
       classyClass(float f=0) {float m_f = f;}

       void setX(int x) { m_x = x; }
       void setY(int y) { m_y = y; }

       int getX() const { return m_x; }
       int getY() const { return m_y; }

    private:
       int m_x;
       int m_y;
};
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You don't have any (private) member `float m_f`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply forgot to declare m_f as a data member of your class.:)

Write

```
//...
    private:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
    float m_f;
```

Comment: I figured it out right after posting this... wonderful! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Because you are declaring a *new* local variable called `m_f` in that position.
2. .. Which will be discarded immediately, because you don't save it in global memory -- it's just a local.
3. ... and a typical modern compiler will notice the assignment to a further unused local variable and optimize this instruction out.

Possibly you meant to save `m_f` in your class; if so, you have to declare it inside that, just like you did for `m_x` and `m_y`.